# Exception safety with shared_ptr's constructor

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, exception-safety

In *Effective C++ 3/E*, I read this:

> This is exception unsafe code:

```
class Test { };
void foo(const std::shared_ptr<Test> &ptr, int i);
int bar();
...

foo(std::shared_ptr<Test>(new Test), bar());
```

> Because compiler can implement like this:
>
> 1. run `new Test`
> 2. call `bar()` **<--** if `bar()` throws exception, the object of `Test` allocated by `new Test` cannot be deleted.
> 3. call constructor of `std::shared_ptr<Test>`
> 4. call `foo()`

But in this case, compiler can know there's memory leak. Can't compiler do `delete` automatically if exception is thrown?

In addition, compiler does automatically `delete` in that case:

```
Test *p = new Test;
```

> that is implemented like this:
>
> 1. call `operator new` to allocate memory
> 2. call constructor of `Test`. **If constructor throws exception, memory is automatically deleted.**

Why compiler doesn't do in first case, unlike second case?

Comment: This is why we don't create `shared_ptr` without `std::make_shared`.

Comment: @Chnossos I know, but I think there's no exception-safety problem even if I use constructor of `shared_ptr`. And there are some case that I cannot use `make_shared`. (e.g. creating shared_ptr of class whose constructor isn't public)

Comment: @ikh: In that case, `std::make_shared` can trivially be wrapped by a `TestFactory::make_shared` (or whatever class does have access to the ctor)

Comment: In the second case, it is `operator new` that calls the constructor. Therefore, it is `operator new` that frees any memory it allocated, if the constructor throws. The compiler doesn't have to perform any magic.

Comment: @MSalters I know, but I'm too lazy to do that..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler cannot normally know that there is a memory leak.
Once the code returns from the constructor of `Test`, the
compiler must assume that the object has been fully and
correctly constructed, which could (and often does) mean that
the constructor has registered a pointer to it somewhere, and
that other code will expect to find it.

The standard *could* have specified that an exception will cause
`delete` to be called on all objects newed in the complete
expression it passes through.  There are a number of historical
reasons why this wasn't even considered.  And today, it would
probably break too much existing code.

The standard also could have imposed a strict ordering on the
evaluation of an expression.  This would remove a lot of issues
of undefined behavior, and make code more deterministic (so
tests are more reliable).  Historically, C didn't take this
route because of its impact on optimization; C++ has kept the
rule.

Comment: You'd be effectively introducing special cases for new/delete that aren't there for fopen/fclose etcetera. Possible, but inconsistent.

Comment: @MSalters Good point.  About the only rule change I think could be considered would be imposing an order on the evaluation of expressions.  And there's a lot of opposition to that one on the part of people who write optimizers.